# Promise внутри фунции

Tags: javascript, хеширование, promise

Всем привет, решил создать простую фунцию для конвертации строки в SHA-256

```js
function Hash(message) {
    const text_encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const data = text_encoder.encode(message);
    const message_digest =  crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);
    console.log(message_digest);
    const octets = new Uint8Array(message_digest);
    const  hex = [].map.call(octets, octet =>      octet.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join("");
    return  hex;
  }
hash=Hash("test");
```

И в итоге утыкнулся в промис crypto.subtle.digest();

Функция возвращает пустой результат. Как мне получить вместо промеса захешированную строку?

Comment: @Grundy зачем вы закрыли мой вопрос? Во всех ваших примерах фигурирует console.log(), а не переменная. В итоге я не получил ответа на свой вопрос, не в этом топике, не в прикремпленном.
Если я хотел получить информацию в console.log(); Я бы просто сделал это внутри функции.

Comment: самый первый пример в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554337/186999) как раз демонстрирует получение в переменную.

Comment: в области функции. Если предположим мне нужно создать глобальную переменную для авторизации через токен. Мне весь код взаимодействия писать внутри функции? Я предпологал использовать это как метод.

Comment: _Мне весь код взаимодействия писать внутри функции?_ - да, пока это работает только внутри функции с `async`. Других способов нет.

Comment: Вы убедили меня в неэффективности этого метода. спасибо

Comment: Это единственный эффективный метод.

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function Hash(message) {
    const text_encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const data = text_encoder.encode(message);
    const message_digest = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);
    const octets = new Uint8Array(message_digest);
    const  hex = [].map.call(octets, octet =>      octet.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join("");
    return  hex;
  }
const hash = Hash("test");
hash.then(console.log);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я пытался сделать асинхронную фунцию. Но задача не стоит для того что бы вывести хеш в консоль. Очень много таких примеров было.

В переменной hash я планирую не промес, а именно строку с хешем

Comment: Пока этот промис не выполнится, вы не можете получить результат из функции. Так что вам надо обрабатывать это поведение асинхронно.